# Error in send email by smtp use PEAR Mail package in php

Tags: php, email, smtp, imap, pear

I am using this code to send message by SMTP and have below error:

What is the problem?

My IMAP is on and username and password are correct and apps access to gmail is on

```
<?php
include 'Mail.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php' ;

$from = "Robert Davis <mymail@gmail.com>";
$to = "Sam Hill <receiver>";
$subject = 'Test mime message with an attachment';

$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

$text = 'Text version of email';// text and html versions of email.
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email. <strong>This should be bold</strong></body>        </html>';

$file = './sample.txt'; // attachment
$crlf = "\n";

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

//do not ever try to call these lines in reverse order
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "mymail";
$password = "mypass";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true  'username' => $username,'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}

?>
```

This is error that i see:

authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response: 5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 x67sm2291331iod.22 - gsmtp)]

Comment: what happens when you log in with your web browser as suggested by the error message?